# Why Is 浜 (bīn) Used So Much In Panda Names?

Tags: names

浜 (**bīn**) seems to be a very common character in the names of pandas. For example:

- 爱浜
- 良浜
- 樱浜
- 桃浜
- 梅浜
- 永浜
- 雄浜

just to name a few.

- Why Is 浜 (**bīn**) Used So Much In Panda Names?

Comment: No, it's not a Chinese name. These pandas all born at a Japanese zoo called `日本和歌山白浜野生动物园`, `浜` just come from the name of the zoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not so popular in China. However, a lot of pandas are born in Japan, where they are named with the character 浜. It's probably due to the name of the Shirahama zoo ([Adventure World](https://www.aws-s.com/en/), 白浜野生动物园, アドベンチャーワールド) where they are born.

Answer (score 2):

This 浜 is not a Chinese character. It is a Japanese character. :)

An'an, Jiajia，Tuantuan, Yuanyuan. Chinese panda names almost always use doubled characters. They're cute!

[image]